# Jquery Mobile and .load function

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to transfer my website into jquery mobile and am running into an error when using:

```
$('#information').load('getRegister.php'  , function() {
                    $('#preloader').hide(); 
                });
```

This function gets called to load html code dynamicaly into the page without a refresh, but the code that appears does not match the css of code already in the website. You can see this in the screenshot below[image]:

I am pretty stumped on why, the buttons and text fields do not take on the styling of the form already loaded into the page. The code the .load calls is this php file:

```
<?php
  require ('myConnectDB.inc.php');     

// echo registration form

echo "

<p class=\"center\"> &nbsp;</p>

<form name=\"input2\" action=\"\" onsubmit =  \" return register()\" method=\"post\"  data-ajax=\"false\">
                    <p class=\"center\"> User Name: 
                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"  id=\"userRegister\" /></p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> Email: 
                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"  id=\"emailRegister\" /></p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"passwordRegister1\" /></p> 
                    <p class=\"center\"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> Re-Type Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" id=\"passwordRegister2\" /></p> 
                    <p class=\"center\"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p class=\"center\"> 
                    <input type=\"submit\"  class=\"  button blue\" name = \"login\" value=\"Register\" />
                    </p>
            </form>";   
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the `create` event on the newly added content.

From the [Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html)

> If you should generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   AJAX and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (see below).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs
>
> and buttons in this case) into the enhanced versions. The code for
>   this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

In your case you will probably want to something like the following

```
$('#information').load('getRegister.php'  , function() {
        $('#preloader').hide(); 
        $('#information').trigger("create");
 });
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. You answered so quickly i can not mark your answer as the right one yet. but in 3 minutes I will!

Comment: Your welcome, if you haven't already I'd suggest you also read the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) about linking pages and the difference between loading a page via ajax or a full post.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your new html doesn't provide the same class attributes as the original form or whatever nested div structure the original style sheet uses.

Look at the class attribute of the original text fields and match those. or look at the style sheet to see how to layout your html.